# How can I flash a castellated ESP32?

Tags: programming, esp32

I want to download firmware to a castellated ESP32 board ([ESP32-C3-WROOM-02-N4](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/891/Espressif_Systems_04082021_ESP32_C3_WROOM_02-2295851.pdf)).

Unlike the commonly used development boards, this one does not have a USB connector. How can this board be programmed?

Comment: Maybe supply a picture of the board. I think there is another solution; a header you can use, of a tag connect etc.

Comment: NB: like the ESP-prog. It saves the USB chips, also consumed power..

Answer (score 10):

You need to connect it as shown in Fig 4 of your datasheet, at least to power, reset and serial. A usb-serial chip as in the [development kit](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/hw-reference/esp32c3/user-guide-devkitc-02.html) (soldered, not socketed, module) would allow programming from USB.

[image]

One way to program the modules before soldering is to fire up your 3D printer and create a custom socket/development system using a handful of pogo pins and an inexpensive USB-serial module.

[image]

You’ll find more information and links in [this](https://hackaday.com/2019/12/07/simple-pogo-programmer-for-esp8266-modules/) hackaday article. You can also find some unofficial purpose-build devices from the [usual suspects](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_DeyMdX9) overseas.

Answer (score 6):

As it needs to be soldered onto some end application PCB anyway, that PCB must power it and contain interface to allow the module to go into programming mode and allow connecting a PC for programming it.